Gronwall's inequality in discretized time
$
\newcommand{\RR}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\TT}{\mathbb{T}}
\newcommand{\NN}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\PP}{\mathbb{P}}
\newcommand{\EE}{\mathbb{E}}
\newcommand{\FF}{\mathbb{F}}
\newcommand{\PPP}{\mathscr{P}}
\newcommand{\KKK}{\mathscr{K}}
\newcommand{\eps}{\varepsilon}
\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}
$
We fix $T \in (0, \infty)$ and let $\TT := [0, T]$. For $n\in \NN^*$, let $\eps_n := T/n$ be the time step and $f_n : \TT \to \RR_+$ bounded measurable. We define $\tau^n_t := \lfloor t/ \eps_n \rfloor \eps_n$ for $t \in \TT$. We assume that
$$
f_n(t) \le f_n(0) + \int_0^t f_n (\tau^n_s) \diff s,
\quad \forall t \in \TT.
$$

Is there a constant $C>0$ independent of $n$ such that $\sup_{t \in \TT} f_n (t) \le C f_n (0)$?

Thank you so much for your elaboration!

After emigrating from Sweden to US, Grönwall spelled his name Gronwall, in particular, in the publication containing his inequality. It is thus the Gronwall inequality.

@JochenWengenroth : The Wikipedia article is aware of the change of the spelling, and yet the spelling there is "Grönwall's inequality". I have never seen "the Gronwall inequality" or "Gronwall's inequality" elsewhere. I guess custom sometimes neglects/overrules history. That Grönwall changed the spelling of his name in America may have been due to the fact that ö is typographically difficult in America.

@IosifPinelis : "I have never seen "the Gronwall inequality" or "Gronwall's inequality" elsewhere". Contrary to that, earlier I have only seen "Gronwall ..." but only recently in a PDE book of a Swedish mathematician (whose name just now doesn't come to my mind) I saw the form "Grönwall ...". For example, in Wloka's PDE book it is "Gronwall ...".

The book I referred to above is Hans Ringström's The Cauchy Problem in General Relativity. It e.g. contains an exceptionally detailed treatment of symmetric hyperbolic systems.

Let $g_n(t):=f_n (\tau^n_t)$; here and in what follows, $t\in[0,T]$. Then
$$g_n(t)=f_n (\tau^n_t)\le f_n(0)+\int_0^{\tau^n_t} g_n(s)\,ds
\le f_n(0)+\int_0^t g_n(s)\,ds,$$
because $\tau^n_t\le t$ and $g_n\ge0$. So, by Grönwall's inequality,
$$g_n(t)\le f_n(0)e^t$$
and hence
$$f_n(t)\le f_n(0)+\int_0^t g_n(s)\,ds
\le f_n(0)e^t\le Cf_n(0),$$
where $C:=e^T$. $\quad\Box$

Another (more direct) proof without using Gronwall's inequality (or any continuity assumptions.)
For all $k\in \{ 0,\cdots,n \}$, denote $t_k=k\varepsilon_n$. The assumption says that, if $t_k \leq t \leq t_{k+1}$, then
$$
f(t)\leq f(0) + \sum_{p=0}^{k-1}f(t_p)\varepsilon_n + f(t_p)(t-t_k).
$$
In particular, for $k=0$, one has
$$
f(t)\leq f(0) + f(0)t \leq f(0)(1+\varepsilon_n) := f(0)A_0.
$$
More generally, one has (by direct induction), for $t_k \leq t \leq t_{k+1}$
$$
f(t)\leq f(0)A_k,
$$
where $A_k$ satisfies $A_{k}=(1+\varepsilon_n)A_{k-1}$. Hence (and since the $A_k$'s are increasing)
$$
\sup_{[0,T]} f\leq f(0)A_{n-1} = f(0)\left(1+\frac{T}{n}\right)^n \leq f(0)e^T,
$$
as $1+x\leq e^x$ for every real number $x$. Therefore, one could take $C=e^T$.
